# Windows 7 Embedded & .NET 4

Tags: windows-7, embedded, .net-framework

Can you update the .NET framework on Windows 7 Embedded to the 4 framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make sure that the *Windows Update Standalone Installer* component is part of your image. According to [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/quebecmisc/thread/39fde7ad-2d00-41de-8921-206bf03c35f8) it should work.

Comment: It does work.  I regularly install .NET 4.5.1 on my WES7 images for an internal application.  You can get a profile that shows all the required components from Microsoft [link](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/catcatalog.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and as the MSDN article points out make sure the following packages are installed in your image of Windows Embedded 7. Using Image Configuration Editor or Image Build Wizard.

- Windows Installer
- Windows Update Standalone Installer
- Standalone Installer .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5

To automate the install of .NET 4.0 you could add a command line entry in Image Configuration Editor in the following way:

Insert-> Synchronous Command->Pass 7 oobeSystem
C:\Setup_Files\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe /passive

Of course make sure C:\Setup_Files. contains dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe.  This can be done in Image Configuration Editor as well.

Comment: Hopefully Microsoft will eventually add support for .NET 4.0 like they did for 2-3.5 and save us all a ton of effort...